# Swift collectionView method not changed for visible cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` which has a cell that's offset, showing the user that there's more to scroll. The problem is the offset cell should have a padlock with an alpha of 1. This does work when I've scrolled around as the cell gets reused and the check is performed.

The method inside checking for purchased courses doesn't get called on the offset cell on initial load.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if let purchased = purchasedCourses {
        if !purchased.contains(courses[indexPath.row].type) {
            print("CELL: \(indexPath.row)")
            cell.padlock.alpha = 1
        }
    }
...
}
```

Is there a way to solve this?

I've tried: `layoutIfNeeded()`, `setNeedsLayout()` `reloadItems()`

Comment: Managed to solve this with a collectionView.reloadData() inside viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
if !purchased.contains(courses[indexPath.row].type) {
        print("CELL: \(indexPath.row)")
        cell.padlock.alpha = 1
     }
     else {

         cell.padlock.alpha = 0
}
```

**OR**

```
 cell.padlock.alpha = purchased.contains(courses[indexPath.row].type ? 0 : 1
```

Comment: The existing method already works, except when the offset cell is visible at the start.

Answer (score 0):

put `else` clause after `if` clause and set default behaviour of cell in `else` part. Here cell are getting reused, so when your if condition gets true, all the other cells will get same property as you didn't provided `else` to get cell in its default case.

```
if !purchased.contains(courses[indexPath.row].type) {
        print("CELL: \(indexPath.row)")
        cell.padlock.alpha = 1
}else {
    cell.padloack.alpha = //your default value of alpha
}
```

Comment: The method already works once the cell goes out of view and comes back. just not at the start!